# Curl stopped working without changes to Apache or PHP

Tags: php, apache, curl

Seem to be in a bit of a predicament. As far as I am aware, there have been no changed to PHP or Apache, however a code that has worked for almost 6 months just stoped working today at 2pm.

The code is:

```
function ls_record($prospectid,$campid){
            $api_post = "method=NewProspect&prospect_id=".$prospectid."&campaign_id=".$campid;

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_post);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://XXXXX/XXXXXX/store.php");
            $x = print_r(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);
            return $x;
    }
```

It returns `NULL, I tried using`file_get_contents()`which also returns`NULL`. I checking the Apache error logs and see nothing...I need some help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the command line of the server? It could be that the destination has blocked you somehow.

If you have command line access, try this

```
wget http://XXXXX/XXXXXX/store.php
```

That should at least return something (if not headers)

Comment: in this scenario the file it is curling is actually on itself. If I go to the URL from a browser, the intended functionality works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

use [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/curl_getinfo) to check your curl execution status, it maybe that the server you try to extract content from need your curl to set user-agent, some site check user-agent to block unwanted curl access.

below are the user agent I used to disguise my curl as desktop chrome browser.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36');
```

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem on my server , because of the low internet speed. Internet speed is go down for some time and curl take so many time to execute , so it return a timeout error . After a few minute it is working fine without any changes on server.